# Error while displaying the PDF column using select query

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

```
 PdfPTable tabl11 = new PdfPTable(8);
            string connect19 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn19 = new SqlConnection(connect19);
            cn19.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd19 = new SqlCommand("select  distinct * from (select p1.PubID,p2.Publisher,p2.Title,p.name as authors from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='A' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID  and p.FID=@FID ) t1 inner join (select p.Name as coauthors,p2.PubID,p2.Type,p2.Title,p2.PubDate,p2.Publisher from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='C' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID and p1.PubID=4 ) t2 on t1.PubID = t2.PubID ", cn19);
            cmd19.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FID", Session["FID"]);
            SqlDataReader rdr11 = cmd19.ExecuteReader();
            if (!rdr11.Read())
            {
                tabl11.DeleteBodyRows();
                cn19.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                tabl11.SpacingBefore = 10f;
                bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
                times = new Font(bfTimes, 12f, Font.UNDERLINE);
                para = new Paragraph("Publication:", times);
                para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                doc.Add(para);
                cell.Colspan = 3;
                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                cell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Pub ID", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Publisher", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Title", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Authors", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Co-Authors", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Type", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Title", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase("Publication Date", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));

                string connect6 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connect6))
                {
                    string query = "select * from (select p1.PubID,p2.Publisher,p2.Title,p.name as authors from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='A' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID   ) t1 inner join (select p.Name as coauthors,p2.PubID,p2.Type,p2.Title,p2.PubDate from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='C' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID  ) t2 on t1.PubID = t2.PubID ";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[0].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[1].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[2].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[3].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[4].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[5].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[6].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl11.AddCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToDateTime(sdr[7]).ToShortDateString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                tabl11.AddCell(cell);
                tabl11.SpacingAfter = 30f;
                doc.Add(tabl11);
            }
```

This above code is used to display the database columns in **PDF**.But the above query what i have used

```
select * from 
(select p1.PubID,p2.Publisher,p2.Title,p.name as authors 
from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='A' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID   ) t1 
inner join 
  (select p.Name as coauthors,p2.PubID,p2.Type,p2.Title,p2.PubDate 
   from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
   where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='C' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID  ) t2 
   on t1.PubID = t2.PubID
```

has **four rows** but while displaying it in the `PDF` it shows only `one` row.How to solve it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The line `PdfPTable tabl11 = new PdfPTable(8);` creates an 8 column table but your comments say that the database has 4 columns. Further, you say "four columns but while displaying it in the PDF it shows only one row". The number of columns doesn't affect the number of rows, you'll need to explain better the problem. What is the `cell` variable. Please update the above by removing code that is not part of the problem (cell, para, times, FontFactory, etc). Also, since we don't have your database it would help if you gave us something reproducible like an array of arrays.

Comment: You are not closing the sql connections cn19 and SqlDataReader rdr11. Also the two queries are having differences in where condition. Is that valid?

Comment: alternatively you can create an sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ to help us understand your problem

Comment: where is `cell` defined? and what is its purpose? it may have something to do with it. I would also breakpoint inside the while loop and ensure it really is looping 4 times as you suggest.

Comment: Have you checked whether the `while (sdr.Read())` loop actually is executed four times as @DavidEwen proposed? If you have and it is, please supply the PDF generated.

Comment: Have you sure that whe `while` loop is running 4 times?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**
The query below will get only 7 column, not 8. so ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurs.

```
select * from 
(select p1.PubID,p2.Publisher,p2.Title,p.name as authors 
from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='A' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID   ) t1 
inner join 
  (select p.Name as coauthors,p2.PubID,p2.Type,p2.Title,p2.PubDate 
   from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
   where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='C' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID  ) t2 
   on t1.PubID = t2.PubID
```

**The answer:**

```
select * from 
(select p1.PubID,p2.Publisher,p2.Title as firsttitle,p.name as authors 
from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='A' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID   ) t1 
inner join 
  (select p.Name as coauthors,p2.PubID,p2.Type,p2.Title,p2.PubDate 
   from Personal_det p,Publication_Tracker p1,Publication_det p2 
   where p.FID=p1.FID and p1.Contribution_Type='C' and p1.PubID=p2.PubID  ) t2 
   on t1.PubID = t2.PubID
```